# How to remove selection to all DataGrids?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've a `StackPanel` that contains three different `DataGrid`, this is the structure:

```
<StackPanel orientation="Vertical" x:Name="DataGridContainer">
    <DataGrid />
    <DataGrid />
    <DataGrid />
</StackPanel>
```

each `DataGrid` bind a different `ItemSource`, and each `DataGrid` bound the same `SelectionChanged` event.

What I need to do is remove the `Selection` from all the DataGrid, except on the clicked one.

Suppose that the `SelectionChanged` event is this:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    /*
       1. Get the DataGrid selected by the user
       2. Get all the DataGrids contained in DataGridContainer
       3. Iterate over all controls and remove the selection except for the DataGrid saved on the step1
    */
}
```

how can I get all the DataGrid of `DataGridContainer` and apply this logic?

**UPDATE**

What I tried:

```
var datagrid = (DataGrid)sender;
var datagridList = DataGridContainer.Children.OfType<DataGrid>();

foreach(var dt in datagridList)
{
    if(dt != datagrid)
    {
         dt.UnselectAll();
    }
}
```

doesn't seems to working, the datagridList is empty

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnselectAll()` triggers a new `SelectionChanged` event. Try this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="DataGridContainer"
            DataGrid.SelectionChanged="DataGridContainer_SelectionChanged"
            xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <s:String>A</s:String>
        <s:String>A</s:String>
        <s:String>A</s:String>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <s:String>B</s:String>
        <s:String>B</s:String>
        <s:String>B</s:String>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <s:String>C</s:String>
        <s:String>C</s:String>
        <s:String>C</s:String>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

---

```
private bool _handle = true;
private void DataGridContainer_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_handle)
    {
        var datagrid = e.OriginalSource as DataGrid;
        if (datagrid != null)
        {
            var datagridList = DataGridContainer.Children.OfType<DataGrid>();
            foreach (var dt in datagridList)
            {
                if (dt != datagrid)
                {
                    _handle = false;
                    dt.UnselectAll();
                    _handle = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```